# Accessing fields from other orgs fetched using REST

Tags: apex

I am fetching records from another org. The sObject type of those records is defined on a managed package that is installed on both orgs, but, in the query that gets the records on the target org, I get a field that is defined on that sobject BUT not for the package but locally to that org. How do I access that field on my source org?

This is the query on the target org that returns the sobjects:

```
List<ERPvs__Productos_Comprobante_de_Venta__c> prods = [SELECT Id,
                                                                   Name,
                                                                   ERPvs__Cantidad__c,
                                                                   ERPvs__Cantidad_1__c, 
                                                                   ERPvs__Cantidad_2__c, 
                                                                   USD_Per_Net_Ton__c
                                                            FROM   ERPvs__Productos_Comprobante_de_Venta__c
                                                            WHERE  ERPvs__Comprobante__r.PO__c = :suppInvoicePo];
```

The field "USD_Per_Net_Ton__c", as you can see, is local to that org, and the others are defined on the "ERPvs" package.

if I reference that field on my source org like this:

```
supi.USD_Per_Net_Ton__c = pcv.USD_Per_Net_Ton__c; //Where pcv is the sobject returned from the target org
```

I get a "Variable does not exist: USD_Per_Net_Ton__c" error. What is the correct way to access that field?

Answer (score 0):

Since it is locally defined field in that Managed Package installed object, you need to deploy that field in both orgs. You can use any of the metadata deployment tools or you can also create the field manually in both orgs.

Comment: Yeah, I understand this, but its not convenient as I will have to get records of sObject types that do not exist on my source org, so I will use wrapper classes to send the data. Thanks anyway!